# wxPython: How to use multiple windows?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I am making a program that gives you a list of artists to choose from and when you click on the artist it opens a new window and gives you a selection of their paintings. However, when I try to do this nothing happens on the new window. I can't put any buttons on it and even static text doesn't work on it, it works just fine on the parent window, but not the child window. Am I missing something or do I need to do something else completely? Here's my code:

```
import webbrowser
import sqlite3
import wx

conn = sqlite3.connect("dbPaintings.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblPaintings(Artist TEXT, PaintingName TEXT, Link TEXT)")
path = 'Artists Paintings.txt'

def insertingPaintings():
    line = ''
    filePaintings=open(path,'r')
    for x in range(15):
        arrPaintings = filePaintings.readline().split(",")
        if len(arrPaintings) == 3:
            strArtist = arrPaintings[0]
            strPainting = arrPaintings[1]
            strLink = arrPaintings[2]
            strLink = strLink.split("\\")[0]
            c.execute("INSERT INTO tblPaintings(Artist, PaintingName, Link) VALUES(:ArtistName, :Painting, :Url)", {'ArtistName':strArtist,'Painting':strPainting,'Url':strLink})
            conn.commit()
#insertingPaintings()

class ArtFrame(wx.Frame):
    def  __init__(self, keyID, title, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent,title=title,size=(800,600))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Working",(566,345))
        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        if keyID=='Auguste Renoir':
            self.AugusteRenoirWork()
    def AugusteRenoirWork(self):
        UmbrellasButtonImage = wx.Image('The Umbrellas.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
        UmbrellasButton = wx.BitmapButton(wx.Panel(self),-1,UmbrellasButtonImage,pos=(200,200),size=(200,250))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs, size=(1280,720), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        self.basicGUI()
        self.Centre()

    def basicGUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('black')
        self.SetTitle('French Impressionism')

        font=wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)

        AugusteRenoirButtonImage = wx.Image('Auguste Renoir.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
        AugusteRenoirText = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Auguste Renoir",(237,345))
        AugusteRenoirText.SetForegroundColour("#e6b800")
        AugusteRenoirText.SetFont(font)
        AugusteRenoirButton = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,AugusteRenoirButtonImage,pos=(220,85),size=(200,250))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.RenoirWindow,AugusteRenoirButton)

        ClaudeMonetButtonImage = wx.Image('Claude Monet.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
        ClaudeMonetText = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Claude Monet",(566,345))
        ClaudeMonetText.SetForegroundColour("#206020")
        ClaudeMonetText.SetFont(font)
        ClaudeMonetButton = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,ClaudeMonetButtonImage,pos=(540,85),size=(200,250))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.MonetWindow,ClaudeMonetButton)

        VincentVanGoghButtonImage = wx.Image('Vincent Van Gogh.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
        VincentVanGoghText = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Vincent Van Gogh",(862,345))
        VincentVanGoghText.SetForegroundColour("#3385ff")
        VincentVanGoghText.SetFont(font)
        VincentVanGoghButton = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,VincentVanGoghButtonImage,pos=(860,85),size=(200,250))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.VanGoghWindow,VincentVanGoghButton)

        GeorgesSeuratButtonImage = wx.Image('Georges Seurat.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
        GeorgesSeuratText = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Georges Seurat",(393,640))
        GeorgesSeuratText.SetForegroundColour("#990099")
        GeorgesSeuratText.SetFont(font)
        GeorgesSeuratButton = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,GeorgesSeuratButtonImage,pos=(380,380),size=(200,250))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.SeuratWindow,GeorgesSeuratButton)

        PaulCezanneButtonImage = wx.Image('Paul Cezanne.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
        PaulCezanneText = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Paul Cezanne",(735,640))
        PaulCezanneText.SetForegroundColour("#cc2900")
        PaulCezanneText.SetFont(font)
        PaulCezanneButton = wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,PaulCezanneButtonImage,pos=(710,380),size=(200,250))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.CezanneWindow,PaulCezanneButton)

        self.Show(True)

    def RenoirWindow(self,event):
        wx.Panel(self)
        title = "Auguste Renoir's Works"
        keyID='Auguste Renoir'
        frame = ArtFrame(parent=wx.GetTopLevelParent(self),title=title,keyID=keyID)
        frame.Show(True)

    def MonetWindow(self,event):
        wx.Panel(self)
        title = "Claude Monet's Works"
        keyID='Claude Monet'
        frame = ArtFrame(parent=wx.GetTopLevelParent(self),title=title,keyID=keyID)

    def VanGoghWindow(self,event):
        wx.Panel(self)
        title = "Vincent Van Gogh's Works"
        keyID='Vincent Van Gogh'
        frame = ArtFrame(parent=wx.GetTopLevelParent(self),title=title,keyID=keyID)

    def SeuratWindow(self,event):
        wx.Panel(self)
        title = "Georges Seurat's Works"
        keyID='Georges Seurat'
        frame = ArtFrame(parent=wx.GetTopLevelParent(self),title=title,keyID=keyID)

    def CezanneWindow(self,event):
        wx.Panel(self)
        title = "Paul Cezanne's Works"
        keyID='Paul Cezanne'
        frame = ArtFrame(parent=wx.GetTopLevelParent(self),title=title,keyID=keyID)

app = wx.App()
MainFrame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note it would be easier if you posted a smaller snippet of code that can be run by anyone without the need of your database and jpg's etc

In

```
class ArtFrame(wx.Frame):
def  __init__(self, keyID, title, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent,title=title,size=(800,600))
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Working",(566,345))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('white')
    if keyID=='Auguste Renoir':
        self.AugusteRenoirWork()
def AugusteRenoirWork(self):
    UmbrellasButtonImage = wx.Image('The Umbrellas.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
    UmbrellasButton = wx.BitmapButton(wx.Panel(self),-1,UmbrellasButtonImage,pos=(200,200),size=(200,250))
```

when the wx.BitmapButton is created it has a new panel as its parent wx.Panel(self), instead use the panel that was created in the **init**

something like this

```
class ArtFrame(wx.Frame):
def  __init__(self, keyID, title, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent,title=title,size=(800,600))
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,"Working",(566,345))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('white')
    if keyID=='Auguste Renoir':
        self.AugusteRenoirWork()
def AugusteRenoirWork(self):
    UmbrellasButtonImage = wx.Image('The Umbrellas.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
    UmbrellasButton = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel,-1,UmbrellasButtonImage,pos=(200,200),size=(200,250))
```